# Argumento no es opcional. no puedo llamar a una funcion de temporizador

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Necesito que una funion envíe un correo y luego genere una cuenta regresiva de espera para la respuesta de dicho correo. Tengo scripts para el envio del correo y establecer el tiempo de espera y aparte tengo una funcion de timer. el problema es que cuando lo llamo aparece el error de que el **`argumento no es opcional.`**

```
    Sub Liberador_1()

    SendToMail = "lukasravlic@gmail.com"
    MailSubject = "Validacion de orden de compra pendiente"
    mMailBody = "Estimado Lukas, porfavor liberar orden de compra numero " & Range("A" & r.Row) & " por " & Range("E" & r.Row) & " " & Range("F" & r.Row) & " creada el " & Range("C" & r.Row) & " quedan 1 dias! "
Set mApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mMail = mApp.CreateItem(0)
With mMail
    .To = SendToMail
    .Subject = MailSubject
    .Body = mMailBody
    .Send
    Range("G" & r.Row) = TimeSerial(0, 5, 0)

    End With
timer ("G" & r.Row)
Next r

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub timer(SEL)

     interval = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

     If Range(SEL).Value = 0 Then Exit Sub

     Range(SEL) = Range(SEL) - TimeValue("00:00:01")

     Application.OnTime interval, "timer"

 End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.OnTime interval, "timer"` tienes que pasarle el argumento SEL cuando llames al procedimiento `timer` que tú mismo has codificado